# Creating first .Net MAUI project

Tags: .net, windows, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I tried to create Maui project in windows using visual studio developer command prompt using
**Command :**
`dotnet new maui`

But Its not creating Maui project,Getting Error message **No templates found matching : maui**
I installed the .Net 5 and visual studio 2019 in my machine.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/FAQs

Comment: https://github.com/Redth/dotnet-maui-check/issues/16

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's now recommended to create .NET Maui apps with Visual Studio according to their [current documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/installation).

Older suggestion:

I'd recommend using the [check tool](https://github.com/Redth/dotnet-maui-check) provided. This will install the templates for you and make sure everything else is present to develop using Maui.

> Install: dotnet tool install -g redth.net.maui.check
>
> Run: maui-check --dev
>
> This will check for:
>
> ```
> OpenJdk / AndroidSDK
> .NET 6 Preview SDK
> .NET MAUI / iOS / Android workloads and packs
> .NET MAUI Templates
> Workload Resolver .sentinel files for dotnet and Visual Studio Windows/Mac
> Currently does not install workloads required for WinUI3
> ```

Comment: in the linked github page there's no **check tool** (i thought it is some binary?).

Comment: @LeiYang - Looks like it moved, and I fixed the link but let me update the answer with the official documents.

Answer (score 17):

There is a [known issue](https://github.com/Redth/dotnet-maui-check/issues/16), please install the template manually:

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.Maui.Templates
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help you out:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui

https://github.com/dotnet/net6-mobile-samples

Take a look at the section "Using IDEs":

> **Using IDEs**
>
> IDE integration into Visual Studio, Visual Studio for Mac, and Visual
> Studio Code are a work in progress.
>
> **Visual Studio**
>
> Currently, you can use Visual Studio 2019 16.9 on Windows (with the
> Xamarin workload) with a few manual steps to run iOS & Android apps
> built on .NET 6.

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio integration you need at least 16.11 preview 1. Use the maui-check tool to install/upgrade the prerequisites on your system. The tool is constantly updated to ensure that the latest MAUI capabilities are installed. Every time a new preview comes out (approximately monthly), rerun maui-check.

Answer (score 0):

Download Visual studio 2022 preview the latest version and MAUI all the default templates are avilable now. try steps here - https://www.msdevbuild.com/2021/11/First-Xamarin-MAUI-Mobile-App-Ios-android-windwos-visual-studio-2022.html